# Does a particle which crosses the galaxy straight (not orbiting) suffer MOND's force in MOND theory?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, modified-gravity

Lets suppose a particle coming from intergalatic space crosses a galaxy. The particle is not rotating the galaxy, so it has no angular velocity or acceleration. The particle is attracted to the galaxy with a gravitational force. In MOND, this force is proportional to the acceleration and thus, to angular velocity. Does it experience Newtonian gravity or MOND gravity?

Comment: Why does such an object not experience a gravitational acceleration towards the center of the galaxy, just like the gravitational/ centripetal acceleration of an orbiting object?

Comment: The $a_0$ constant in MOND is pretty much what would answer your question... that's the acceleration above which the classical Newton laws are reproduced (more or less, it's a bit more finely detailed than that)... have you taken a look at it?

Comment: Even an unbound particle has angular velocity